# Form Submit getting called multiple times after success

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Spring boot. I load success.jsp page after execution of the submit controller. I am returning String in the controller. On the browser, after successful execution, success.jsp loads fine but the URL does not change. But if the page refreshes again, the from submits again with all the data from the first submit. I cannot use captcha because of security reason. I am checking the DB before inserting data, but its adding unnecessary DB call.
The configuration are - Spring Boot MVC project.
Configuring a View Resolver -  We would have our jsp’s in /WEB-INF/jsp/.

```
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/submit" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForPayment(@ModelAttribute("paymentForm") PaymentInfo paymentInfo, 
    BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) { 
    .......... 
    return "success";
    }
```

I need to stop submission of the page when the page refreshes after I show success.jsp.

Comment: Can you please share your code for submission of form. Maybe the issue is in JS where the event needs to be stopped triggering.

Comment: Could you share the code where you submit the form as well as how you handle the response please.?